# Setting up Dialogflow CX to save audio recordings in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have setup a Google Cloud Storage bucket in the same project as my Dialogflow CX Agent, and in the settings for the agent, under the Speech & IVR tab, set the Google Cloud Storage URI to match that bucket:

```
gs://my-bucket/calls
```

I can see that the Dialogflow Agent has access to the bucket as it has a Service Agent listed in the Permissions tab of the bucket.
Furthermore, since I successfully enabled logging, I can see that the bucket is correctly configured, as in the log payload I can see the following property:

```
interactiveVoiceResponseSettings: {
  audioExportGcsDestination: {
    uri: "gs://my-bucket/calls"
  }
}
```

However, when making calls, nothing appears on that bucket's folder.
Is there another configuration option I'm missing to enable this feature?
Or perhaps it is not yet functional?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Google Cloud Storage URI' option in the Dialogflow CX Speech and IVR agent settings is currently supported for the following use cases:

1. If you use 1-click telephony partner integrations (for example,
   [AudioCodes](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/audiocodes) or [Avaya](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/avaya))
2. If you use the [Contact Center AI](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/contact-center) solution
   provided by Google partners.

If you use 1-click telephony partner integrations, and the 'Google Cloud Storage URI' option is not working for you, please check the following:

- Go to the GCP project IAM and find the automatically created service account of the format *one-click@df-cx-<ALPHANUMERIC_VALUE>-<ALPHANUMERIC_VALUE>.iam.gserviceaccount.com*
- Make sure that this service account has the 'GCS Storage Bucket Owner' role assigned to it.

Note that the 'Google Cloud Storage URI' option doesn't support the detect Intent API requests.